# What will happen if I run rollabck without begin in PostgresSQL statement?

Tags: postgresql, psql, auto-commit

I have run below statement without begin then, show a warning message
(**WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress**)
like below image. But actually that table was deleted. Why it is not roll backed? Is there any effect in future transaction on that table?

[image: rollback without begin]

Answer (score 3):

[Autocommit is on by default](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#id-1.9.4.20.8.5.2.9.1.1.2) in `psql`, so every statement is implicitly committed. In other words, after `delete` a `commit` was issued by the driver, which closed the active transaction, then obviously `rollback` didn't do anything and resulted in the warning you saw.